# easily install ubuntu applications without using terminal

Tags: software-installation

I just recently installed ubuntu and i really dont know much about it, i want to know how to easily install applications on ubuntu, cuz i have installed utorrent and teamviewer through terminal using tutorial online. but using terminal and watching tutorial of how to install applications too much, if there is any easy way like in windows double click and next next for tar.gz files or any other applications.

like i have downloaded a file

```
https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en
```

and now i want to install it,but i dont know how cuz i will have to use terminal for this and i am not good in using terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Overall the key to using linux efficiently is the terminal but if you want TOR working all you have to do is open a file manager, unzip the file, then run the shell file inside. If double clicking on it does nothing but open gedit to edit it then you need to go into the terminal, type `cd /path/to/compressed/file/` then `./<filename>` to launch it.

Answer (score 2):

If your application is released also as a .deb file, you can download and open it with "GDebi package installer".

To install gdebi on Debian, Ubuntu or Linux Mint, run the following.

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

The gdebi utility has two components: gdebi for a command-line tool, and gdebi-gtk for graphical front-end.
You have to right click on the file> Open with> GDebi... Wait for the check, then click on Install package.

BTW, terminal is the quickest way to do anything in Linux (and maybe not only in Linux). E.g., you can quickly install your application via terminal with
`sudo dpkg -i DEBIAN_PACKAGE` or
`sudo gdebi DEBIAN_PACKAGE`